# Decoding JSON and map it to existing object Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I have the following object

```
struct Properties: Decodable {
    var id: String?
    var value: String?
    var color: String?
}
```

In the first request to server I get the following response

```
{ 
   "id":"1",
   "color":"red"
}
```

And after another request I get

```
{ 
   "id":"1",  // the id of the object props is meant for 
   "props":{ 
      "value":"my value" // I can get any property here
   }
}
```

After the two requests I should have the object with all properties set

By now I decode the second request as following

```
struct SetAttr: Decodable {

    let id: String
    let props: [String : Any]

    enum SetAttrCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case props
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try! decoder.container(keyedBy: SetAttrCodingKeys.self)
        props = try! container.decode([String : Any].self, forKey: .props)
        id = try! container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

    }
}
```

But I do not know how to parse `props` dictionary and set the properties on the first object. I am willing to use a decoding library, but I did not find any that can do this

EDIT:

This is how I tried to set the properties from dictionary, but the solution is not scalable

```
var myObject: Properties
properties = setAttr.props // [String:Any]

let keys = properties.keys

keys.forEach { key in

    if let value = properties[key] {

        switch key {
        case "value":
            myObject.value = value as? String
        case "color":
            myObject.color = value as? String
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need two steps anyway to create and populate the struct I recommend to decode the `props` request with traditional `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Is the solution for this really related to json?

Comment: @vadian ok, but how to map it the previous object

Comment: Specify CodingKeys `id` and `color` in `Properties` and decode the first response with `JSONDecoder`. Then decode the second response with `JSONSerialization` and update the `Properties` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSONSerialization which parses whatever you throw at it into arrays and dictionaries. That frees you from all the problems you have with strangely formatted JSON.

For example, the second request will be parsed as a dictionary with two keys "id" and "props", and "props" has a value which is again a dictionary with one key "value" and a value "my value".

And please stop using try! That will cause your app to crash instantly if any input is not expected. Unexpected inputs should be handled, not lead to a crash.

Comment: I successfully parsed the second json into a dictionary [String:Any], the big problem is how to set the properties on the previous received object, I could do a switch that depending on property name set it accordingly, but I think there must be a more wise solution

Comment: @SorinLica Given your comments I think it is something essential you have forgotten to mention in your question because by the looks of it the matching should be trivial but apparently it isn't. In your comment here you mention property name that is not part of the quetion, what is that? Please don't answer this question but rather update your question. It would most likely be helpful with more examples and and a clarified explanation of what a property is.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The matching is not that trivial, please see my edit in question, by property name I mean "enabled", "color", etc. I just made up this simple example to describe my problem, in the real case I have about 50 different objects each of them having different properties, so I am looking for a generic solution

Answer (score 0):

There are various way to do this, but one possible way could be something like this:

```
struct SecAttr: Decodable {
    let id: String
    var props: Properties?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id
       case props
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)

        if let props = try container.decodeIfPresent(Properties.self, forKey: .props) {
          self.props = props
        } else {
          // decode Properties from the same object
          self.props = try Properties(from: decoder)
        }
    }
}

struct Properties: Decodable {
    var value: String?
    var color: String?

    mutable update(from props: Properties) {
       value = props.value ?? value
       color = color.value ?? color
    }
}
```

Now you can decode your original object and after getting updated properties, just update them on the original.